# Displaying text view texts with two different colors in custom listview

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-custom-view, spannablestring

I am working on a project where i need to display and append two strings "name" and "message" in a single textview of custom lisview with two different colors. For this purpose i used Html text as follows:

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>Chandru</font> <font color=#ffcc00>You have got a notification</font>";
nameTedt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text)); <br>
```

The above piece of code is working like a charm but the problem I am facing is the performance issue in my custom list view (i.e scrolling is not smooth). I even tried spannable text as follows:

```
TextView nameTedt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);    
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Andrew", You have got a message form simmons);          
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 6, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);    
nameTedt.setText(wordtoSpan); <br>
```

But again the problem starts with that I don't know the exact size of the strings "name" and "message". It can be of any size, since am parsing it using JSON. I'd like to use spannable text with two different colors for any number of characters for the strings. Any other solutions would also be appreciated.

The total content of my requirement is as follows.

> Chandru : You have got a message from aisha this morning. Please send her a reply asap if possible. Thanks

It could even be possible with two textviews I hope. But don't know how to proceed with it because my message text should wrap to the next line below my name "chandru". Kindly suggest me to proceed with layouts too.

I am also posting my base adapter class since the performance is low because of html content

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (v == null) {
                v = mLayoutInflater
                        .inflate(R.layout.view_subview, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.nameTedt= (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.nameTedt);


                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }
                      notifyTypeId = NotificationAllAL.get(position).getNotifyType().getNotifytypeId();

            if(notifyTypeId == 1){  

String text = "<font color=#cc0029>"namestring"</font> <font color=#ffcc00>You have got a notification</font>";
nameTedt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));



            }else if(notifyTypeId == 2){  
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>"namestring"</font> <font color=#ffcc00>You have got a email</font>";
nameTedt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));  

            }else if(notifyTypeId == 3){  
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>"namestring"</font> <font color=#ffcc00>You have got a message</font>";
nameTedt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text)); 

            }else if(notifyTypeId == 4){
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>You have got a call from</font> <font color=#ffcc00>"namestring"</font>";
nameTedt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));    

            }  <br>
```

The name string should be in blue and message string should be in orange.

Comment: you're sure that the performance decrease is caused by using HTML.fromHtml?

Comment: @suitianshi yes of course performance is very low

Comment: Are the colors fixed? Is there any reasons not to use 2 `TextView`s instead?

Comment: yes we can use two textviews. But the format should be like

Comment: Chandru: You have got a message. Please pick the message Asap

Comment: The message text should wrap to next line according to the name

Comment: like a normal chat window with name with one color and message with another color. Textview with two layouts can also be possible. But i dont know how to proceed with it

Comment: I just realized that limitation... I couldn't do it with 2 `TextView`s. Also, is there any delimiter between the name and the message? I see that on the example HTML code, there isn't, but on below, there is ":" (colon).

Comment: colon is not a delimiter. just i posted for the sample purpose. Generally used to append message with name string from the json response.